# Parsing JS in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing

I'm trying to get some data that's being used to plot a chart in a certain website. The data I need is in tree of 'data' key:value pairs in one of the  tags. They all have the following structure, that is, they are all json arguments passed to the Chart constructor:

```js
    var geral_chart = document.getElementById('geralChart').getContext('2d');
    var geralChart = new Chart(geral_chart, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["14/05","15/05","16/05","17/05", etc]
        datasets: [{
          data: [79, 87, 93, ... etc ]]}
```

I've acessed the DOM content with requests/bs4, and I have the whole content I need to parse as a string, I just have no idea on how to proceed to get the exact data.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the content always has the same format, its best to use a regex to extract the data part of the argument.

```
import re // Import the re module for regex
regex = "data: \s*{((\s*.*)*)}"gmi
```

Let me explain the regex;

```
'data:' // To start searching from where we see the 'data:' text
'\s*' // To check if there is any amount of spaces before the object starts
'{' // The opening bracket for the data object,
'((\s*.*)*)' // This is the part that gathers the value of the data key, it searches for any character and groups it.
'}' // The closing bracket for the data object
'gmi': // Flags for the search
```

Then you call the `search` method on the `re` module

```
result = re.search(regex, the_original_string)
```

If nothing was found it returns the `None` type

else you then call the `group` method on the `result` to get the value of the data object

```
data_value = result.group(1)
```

Then load the `data_value` with the `json` module

```
import json
data = json.loads(data_value)
```

Comment: Does not work because I only have the full JS code, including the var declarations and etc, while I need to access just JSONs passed as args to the constructor, but not the rest of the content.

Comment: Can I see the part of the content you're trying to parse

Comment: It's the content I've included in the OP. All of that. I just need the 'data' key:value pair, tho.

Comment: Are you trying to parse it with the `var` keyword? Because that would cause an error. If not i've edited my answer

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I got the whole string (including the var declarations), but I only need the argument 'data' that's passed to the Chart constructor, and I have no idea on how to obtain that.

Comment: So how are you getting the data? Is it coming from a JS file?

Comment: I don't think I've been clear enough, sorry. xD I'm getting the JS code from a <script> tag on the HTML code from a page through BeautifulSoup. Of course I could simply copy and paste it in my Python script, but the 'data' argument that I need is updated daily, so I need to automate it so I can get the data whenever it is updated.

Comment: Okay. I've changed my answer